# Can auto update paid app's price - Playstore

Tags: android, google-play

Is there any way to update paid app's price **automatically**?

e.g.
I want to upload app with price $1 for 1 week or 2, After that the price automatically update to $3 for life time.

Comment: check this https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7271135?hl=en

Comment: Great. Thankyou